# How would I get this functionality in my matrix class?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, templates, initializer-list

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

template<typename T, std::size_t R, std::size_t C>
class matrix
{
   std::array<T, R * C> m_data;
};

int main() 
{
   matrix<float, 2, 2> a = { 1,2,3,4 }; // COMPILER ERROR!
}
```

Clang reports that there is **no matching constructor**!

I have tried writing a constructor of the form

```
matrix(std::array<T,R*C> a);
```

and tried experimenting with `&&` as I think the right-hand side of the expression in question is temporary. Which leads me to some confusion. As we would expect that it would be created then assigned(!) to the value of `a`.

Comment: You need a constructor that takes an initializer list. See [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list).

Comment: That answered my question! Thanks. pos that as an answer if you wish

Comment: If you have a constructor that takes an std::array, or if your matrix is an aggregate (make m_data public), you can initialize it with {{1,2,3,4}};   add more braces until it compiles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like others mentioned in the comments, you need a [`std::initializer_list<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) constructor for your `matrix` class.

```
#include <array>            // std::array
#include <initializer_list> // std::initializer_list
#include <algorithm>        // std::copy
#include <cassert>

template<typename T, std::size_t R, std::size_t C>
class matrix
{
   std::array<T, R * C> m_data;
public:
   matrix(const std::initializer_list<T> list)
  //            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ --> constructor which takes std::initializer_list
   {
      assert(R * C == list.size());
      std::copy(list.begin(), list.end(), m_data.begin());
   }
};

int main()
{
   matrix<float, 2, 2> a = { 1,2,3,4 }; // now compiles
}
```

**([See live online](https://godbolt.org/z/OqgnTo))**

---

However, that is not compile-time and come ups with the following drawbacks:

- It does not check the passed types are same.
- Size of the passed list can not be checked compile-time, as `std::initializer_list` is/can not be compile time.
- Thirdly, it allows narrowing conversion.

In order to disallow the above, one solution is to provide a variadic template constructor which enables the above checks compile-time.

Something like as follows:**([See live online](https://godbolt.org/z/j3TCsG))**

```
#include <array>            // std::array
#include <initializer_list> // std::initializer_list
#include <type_traits>      // std::conjunction, std::is_same
#include <utility>          // std::forward     

// traits for checking the types (requires C++17)
template <typename T, typename ...Ts>
using are_same_types = std::conjunction<std::is_same<T, Ts>...>;

template<typename T, std::size_t R, std::size_t C>
class matrix
{
   std::array<T, R * C> m_data;
public:
   template<typename... Ts>
   constexpr matrix(Ts&&... elemets) noexcept
   {
      static_assert(are_same_types<Ts...>::value, "types are not same!");
      static_assert(sizeof...(Ts) == R*C, "size of the array does not match!");
      m_data = std::array<T, R * C>{std::forward<Ts>(elemets)...};
   }
};

int main()
{
   matrix<float, 2, 2> a{ 1.f,2.f,3.f,4.f }; // now compiles
   // matrix<float, 2, 2> a1{ 1,2,3,4 };              // error: narrowing conversion!
   // matrix<float, 2, 2> a1{ 1.f,2.f,3.f, 4 };       // error: types are not same!
   // matrix<float, 2, 2> a1{ 1.f,2.f,3.f,4.f, 5.f }; // error: size of the array does not match!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a [`std::initializer_list<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list).

One of it's drawbacks is that it doesn't check the number of arguments you pass it.

```
template<typename T, std::size_t R, std::size_t C>
class matrix
{
public:
    matrix(const std::initializer_list<T> list) { /*...*/ }
};

int main()
{
    matrix<float, 2, 2> a = { 1,2,3,4 };   // compiles
    matrix<float, 2, 2> b = { 1,2,3,4,5 }; // also compiles
}
```

Instead, use the following:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t R, std::size_t C>
class matrix
{
    std::array<T, R*C> m_data;

public:
    matrix() = default;

    template<typename... Us>
    matrix(Us &&...args) : m_data{static_cast<T>(args)...}
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    matrix<float,2,2> a = {1,2,3};     // ok
    matrix<float,2,2> b = {1,2,3,4};   // ok
    matrix<float,2,2> c = {1,2,3,4,5}; // error
}
```

The cast is necessary to avoid a potential narrowing conversion.